# How to get Symfony to allow filenames as parameters for a module

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony1, apache2

Im trying to have a module that manages downloads for files, so when someone goes to site.com/download/filename.pdf it fires the download module with filename parameter as filename.pdf.

The problem is the rewrite rules on Symfony dont allow that, it would be rewritten. What would I need to add to .htaccess to prevent the rewriting of those urls for .doc and .pdf files? Ive included the .htaccess file below...

Thanks for the help!

```
S

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  RewriteBase /



  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wildcard route:

```
url:  /download/*
```

and point it to the download module.  Whatever route that is entered starting with /download/ will automatically open your download module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon, 
to add to that I also had to change the segment_separators on the route to stop the . being interpreted as a marker for another parameter, so added this to the route for this module in routing.yml:
segment_separators: ['-', '/', '_']